# Add Image To ListAdapter

Tags: android, image, listadapter

I have a SimpleAdapter as follow :

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            ItemDetail.this, itemList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[]{
                            TAG_PID,
                            TAG_NAME,
                            TAG_PICTURE
                    },
                            new int[]{
                                    R.id.pid,
                                    R.id.name,
                                    R.id.img
                            });
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

But there is a problem for images. my images need to get from a web address. I can get them by this code:

```
try {
     final String imageUrl = "http://example.com/pic/jpg";
     InputStream in = (InputStream) new URL(imageUrl).getContent();
     Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
     in.close();
 } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

And finally set image:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
//img is a single item in a list_item xml file
image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

But my question is, how can I merge all of above code ?? download and set image for every item in the list.

Comment: You have to implement your own adapter class.

Comment: how can i do this ? @cricket_007

Comment: You lookup how to write a custom adapter. But, that isn't the only problem. `new URL(imageUrl).getContent()` needs to happen in the background. You can't download images just like that - the app will crash

Comment: I would suggest using the [Picasso library](https://square.github.io/picasso/) anyway, but you can see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33328190/picasso-with-arrayadapter and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23120238/using-picasso-library-with-listview for references for how your code would look like.

Comment: thank you my friend but i want to code my self ( without any external lib )

Comment: is there other way to merge them ? @cricket_007

Comment: `ArrayAdapter` is not an external lib. That is all you need. If you want images, that is a different problem. You say *"I can get them by this code"* - but unless that code is in an AsyncTask, you cannot get that Bitmap

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23120238/using-picasso-library-with-listview?noredirect=1&lq=1